# How to implement this php code?

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, javascript

So I have this php code in my joomla site (joomla's latest article module) and id I'd like to add a bootstrap tooltip to the title of my links. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how i I add this script to a php page. Thanks in advance. Here's the script i got from w3schools.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

**and my code which i already have.**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<div style="float: left;margin-right: 47px;">

<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php   echo $item->title; ?>" itemprop="url"><img src="/images /sound.png" />&nbsp;
    <span itemprop="name">
        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
    </span>
</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add your jQuery code right after your existing code, but Joomla runs jQuery in [noconflict mode](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks#jQuery_JavaScript_Framework), so you have to change `$` to `jQuery`, or wrap your code like this:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
  });
</script>
```

Your entire code would look something like this:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<div style="float: left;margin-right: 47px;">

<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php   echo $item->title; ?>" itemprop="url"><img src="/images /sound.png" />&nbsp;
    <span itemprop="name">
        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
    </span>
</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul></div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried it but no luck. Not sure why. Anyways just so u know Im using the lastest articles module from joomla. Anything I might be missing? Thanks